# AWS SES - Receiving email on S3

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have followed all the steps from this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html

I also believe I have done everything in here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-setting-up.html

My domain has been verified and I have setup the rule as specified in the first link but when I go to the S3 bucket I don't see anything there. I even tried making it public to see if this was permissions or something.

What am I missing here? I want to send an email to info@mydomain and see it in S3.
If there is some other way of getting emails from a domain that I bough in Route 53 please let me know.

I have also setup an MX record on my domain with the following values:

10 inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Every time I send an email to info@mydomain after a while I get an error about the email not being delivered.

What can I do to get this working???

EDIT: The only error I am seeing is from gmail saying:

```
Message not delivered
There was a problem delivering your message to info@example.com. See the technical details below.
LEARN MORE

The response was:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect.
```

I don't want to put the domain because the website is still being built

EDIT 2:
This is what I have for the domain in route 53. The value for the MX record is from [aws ses documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing there is some qualification needed for "If there is some other way of getting emails from a domain that I bough in Route 53 please let me know" as you can of course use any mail service you want.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a good idea to include the domain name in this type of question.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist There is no error that I can see from aws. The only error is when I try to send to the domain email, I get an error from gmail saying that it couldn't deliver the email

Comment: "The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect" - are you accepting port 25 traffic?

Comment: Can you show `dig` output for the `MX` record to show that it's actually in correctly in place? The error message suggests that they are unable to connect to whatever is designated by the MX/address records for the domain.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I have updated the question with all the records. I don't have dig installed on my system (windows 10)

Comment: @Colt I don't have any software installed for mail stuff on the actual ec2 instance. I am only using AWS SES services so I don't think I have to have port 25 opened anywhere on my system

Comment: You might not have `dig` but you will have `nslookup` which can do the same query ... nslookup -type=mx gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have you have an `MX` record at `mail.example.com` (if we use `example.com` as the zone name).

Is that really what you want? Are you actually intending to send mail to `info@mail.example.com`?

If not, make sure the `MX` record resides at the name that you are actually sending mail to (eg at `example.com` -> `info@example.com`).

Comment: Wow... that was dumb of me. I really thought I needed something there. I have just changed the record to just be example.com and sent an email to info@example.com but unfortunately I still don't see anything in the S3 bucket. I will give it some more time. Thanks!

Comment: It's quite possible that the non-existence response for `MX` is cached since your previous attempts (on the Gmail side, if that's what you are testing with).

Comment: @AntonioCS do you see how much more quickly your question would have been solved if you hadn't redacted the domain name?  I'm declining to vote to close this question (it's on the queue for closure) **only** so it can stand as yet another example of [why redaction is unhelpful](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts).

Comment: @MadHatter It wouldn't affect the question. What I should have done at the start is show all the data in route 53.

Comment: @AntonioCS I see your point, but it doesn't hold: the questioner never reliably knows what's relevant, because they don't know what's wrong; that's why they're asking the question.  Give *all* the information you can, and we can probably work out what we don't know, or failing that, ask for what we need.  Make it easy for **us**, not yourself - you're the one asking for a favour.